# duplicate rows in join table with three has_many :through associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Description

I have four models:

1. User
2. Organization
3. Role
4. OrganisationUserRole

The idea is that one user can belong to many organizations and can have many roles, but just one per organization.

My models look like this:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :through => :organization_user_roles
  has_many :organizations, :through => :organization_user_roles
  has_many :organization_user_roles
end
```

**organization.rb**

```
class OrganizationUserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organization_user_roles  
  has_many :users, :through => :organization_user_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :organization_user_roles
end
```

**role.rb**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

**organization_user_role.rb**

```
class OrganizationUserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :role
end
```

I am seeding my db with following seeds.rb

```
require 'faker'

# seed with standard roles

role_list = [
  [ "superadmin" ],
  [ "admin" ], 
  [ "user" ],
  [ "owner" ],
]

role_list.each do |role|
  Role.create( :name => role[0] )
end

# create default superadmin & organization

p = User.create(email: 'thomas@aquarterit.com', password: 'password')
o = Organization.create(name: 'A Quarter IT', website: 'www.aquarterit.com')
o.users << User.find_by_email('thomas@aquarterit.com')
p.roles << Role.find_by_name("superadmin")

# 30 organizations, 3 users each

30.times do |organization|
  o = Organization.create(name: Faker::Company.name, website: Faker::Internet.domain_name)
  3.times do |user|
    p = User.create(email: Faker::Internet.email, password: 'password')
    p.roles << Role.find_by_name("user")
    o.users << User.last
  end
end
```

### Problem

Migrations and rake db:seed run successfully, but afterwards the table

> organization_user_roles

contains duplicate rows per user:

Row 1: User_id 1 -> Organization_id 1

Row 2: User_id 1 -> Role_id 1

How can I associate the user, organization and role at the same time in one row?

Thanks a lot in advance, you guys are are always an amazing help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following the instructions here:

[How to join mutli-role, multi organisation tables in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771503/how-to-join-mutli-role-multi-organisation-tables-in-rails)

And it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a database unique key for the three params, something like

```
add_index "organization_user_roles", ["user_id", "organization_id", "role_id"], name: "unique_roles", unique: true, using: :btree
```

then in your organization_user_role model

```
validates_uniqueness_of :role_id, scope: [:user_id, :organization_id]
```

i did a similar app with unique columns in my db and this solution worked

Answer (score 1):

You need has_many through with 3 tables, look on this link:

[Rails 3 has_many through with 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761414/rails-3-has-many-through-with-3-tables)